# How to get the new kernel when upgrading from 14.04.2 to 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel

After upgrading to `14.04.3` from `14.04.2` (started with `14.04.1`), my kernel is still at `3.13.0-61-generic` — [I'm expecting a variant of `3.19`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Kernel.2BAC8-Support.Ubuntu_Kernel_Support).

How can I upgrade to include the default kernel from `14.04.3`?

```
nathanbrauer@macthan:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

nathanbrauer@macthan:~$ uname -r
3.13.0-61-generic
```

**Bonus question:** Is there anything else that comes default in `14.04.3` but doesn't get installed when upgrading?

Comment: Also graphical stack is not installed.

Answer (score 2):

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

and reboot.

You can also upgrade the graphical stack by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-vivid libgles2-mesa-lts-vivid libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-vivid:i386 libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid
```

You can read more in [Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).

But the upgrade command there is not 100% correct. It may remove some useful packages.

Comment: Why not include `--install-recommends`?  And do I still want `:i386` if I'm on 64-bit?

Comment: I tested and `--install-recommends` does not do anything in this case. And `:i386` packages are added not to remove wine, skype, etc. You can test yourself. If you have a clean Ubuntu without any 32-bit applications, that command will probably do. You will see what is removed before you agree.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the other differences between your recommendation and the Wiki's recommendation? Looks like it has a completely different set of packages. See diff here: http://www.diff-online.com/view/55c90c9f371d0

Comment: It will be too long to explain here. But the result will be the same)). Anyway much more packages will be installed by dependencies. The question is which are enough to pull all needed.

Comment: I added `libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid` just in case. But I upgraded without it with no problem. That package probably will be installed by dependency. You can test it and report @NathanJ.Brauer